# Running a certain test last using maven

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

I am using Maven and the failsafe plugin to execute a set of runners that run integration tests.

One of these runners execute tests that involve altering my configuration. For this reason, I would like this runner to be executed only when the other tests have finished executing. Otherwise, there is the possibility of unrepresentative tests.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Using an appropriate test framework which allows the definition of order like TestNG ?

Comment: @khmarbaise So you're telling me that maven's test framework has no way of defining an order?

Comment: Maven has no Test framework. You are using thing like JUnit or TestNG ...there is a limited way to define the order of tests (see [runOrder](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#runOrder)) but I don't think that this will help you...

Comment: @khmarbaise I'll look into the run order property it looks promising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @khmarbaise comment, in Testng you have annotations that can help you set and reset config files
http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations